# Service registration is missing or corrupt BITS service windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

Microsoft **Edge** and others like **weather** and **windows Store Market** gives errors and does not work and below error 0x80072EE7]

[image]

it is while:

- all my non-Microsoft apps have no problem connecting to internet
- IE and My Windows 10 updates and office apps are connecting

other useful points to consider:

- I have upgraded to windows 10 recently
- I am Behind the corporate Firewall and internet proxy with authentication
- direct internet access also does not fixed the problem
- I have installed proxifier (which i think changed some internal network setting)
- before installing proxifier and adding my 2 corporate email accounts i was able to connect the edge but after installing my apps i am getting this error
- windows update trouble shooter is also complaining about ** related to **BITS service** (Background Intelligent Transfer Service)
- Service registration is missing or corrupt

any help is appreciated

Comment: See this page for Windows Update BITS error...http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/windows-10-service-registration-is-missing-or/a2bfb3c3-665f-4f22-92d9-cf82f0a950be

Answer (score 1):

updating Proxifier from 3.15 to 3.28 and restarting resolved my problem

Comment: Not for me, I have 3.29 and Weather, Store and Edge fail to be detected, while Windows Update works.

Answer (score 1):

For BITS error, we can try the repair steps in this article: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720473(v=ws.10).aspx

Also, for the certain error message, it could be caused by proxy and network issue. Please try the network monitor to capture the trace when reproing this issue, and see where the connection is blocked.

Comment: Kate, your answer needs to include the relevant parts of the link you posted, link only answers are of no use to us here due to eventual link rot.